# How to use SVG sprite in CSS

Tags: css, svg, sprite

I am trying SVG sprite in my project, but its not working as expected, The sprite contains three images as shown below:

[image]

<kbd>[Original Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8l2hx3bslf8owrx/icons.svg)</kbd>

When i call in CSS its showing zoomed in all three images, not particular image whose background-position defined, seems i have to define something additional too, gone through some articles they have defined path, is it required if yes then why and how i can calculate these path, please help

Below what i have tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG POC</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .ico {
                background: transparent url('icons.svg') 0 0 no-repeat; 
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .ico-hotel {
                background-position: 0 0;
                height: 20px;
                width: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>          
        <a href="#"><span class="ico ico-hotel"></span></a>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to use background-size too!

Comment: tryed, but its not working.

Comment: background-size: cover works for me, but face one more issue, i have to change background position every time whenever i change the resolution, working on responsive site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your paths are already defined in the `svg` file

set the width and height in the `svg` and it should work:

add `width="86px" height="20px"`

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="86px" height="20px"
     viewBox="0 0 389.4 91.3" enable-background="new 0 0 389.4 91.3" xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: how u checked the path, is there any tool, where i have to defined the height and width, i got this sprite from design team, do they will do or i have to define

Comment: Didn't you already define it ? height: 20px;width: 20px; at ico-hotel class?

Comment: I don't think that codepen will work with a dropbox url.
Open the icon.svg file with any text editor and you will see the tag I pasted on the answer.
If you don't want to edit the file, you can use background-size to set the right size

Comment: I'm also very curious about this as I'm looking to switch from PNG, but how come there's no decent articles on the matter? The ones I've found are just about icon fonts etc.